# radio button to enable text area

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button

I am still very new to Java and have been trying to figure out how to enable a text area for editing if a radio button is selected for a while now. I have been googling and reading posts on various forums, however i don;t understand what they are doing or how to do it within my program what so ever.

Here is what I have so far:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package labscheduler;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 *
 * @author S02105032
 */
public class FXMLLabSchedulerDocController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtRequestorName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtRequestorEmail;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEventTitle;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNumParticipants;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEventDate;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtStartTime;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtEndTime;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton togStartTime;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton togEndTime;
    @FXML
    private CheckBox chkPrinter;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbYes;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rbNo;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtareaMessage;

    private String requestorName;
    private String requestorEmail;
    private String eventTitle;
    private int participants = 0;
    private Date eventDate;  
    private Date startTime;  
    private Date endTime;  
    private String printer;
    private String message;

    @FXML
    private void handleBtnSubmit(ActionEvent event) {
        requestorName = txtRequestorName.getText();
        requestorEmail = txtRequestorEmail.getText();
        eventTitle = txtEventTitle.getText();
        participants = Integer.parseInt(txtNumParticipants.getText());

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YY");
        try {
            eventDate = sdf.parse(txtEventDate.getText());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("invalid date format");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat stdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        try {
            startTime = stdf.parse(txtStartTime.getText());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("invalid start time format");
        }

        SimpleDateFormat etdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        try {
            endTime = etdf.parse(txtEndTime.getText());
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println("invalid end time format");
        }

        if(chkPrinter.isSelected()) {
            printer = "printer requested";
        }
        else {
            printer = "no printer needed";
        }

        if(rbYes.isSelected() && !rbNo.isSelected()) {
            txtareaMessage.setEditable(true);
            message = txtareaMessage.getText();
        }
        else {
            txtareaMessage.setEditable(false);
            message = "None";
        }

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonClose(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Application Close!");
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonClear(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Clear All Fields!");
        txtRequestorName.setText("");
        txtRequestorEmail.setText("");
        txtEventTitle.setText("");
        txtNumParticipants.setText("");
        txtEventDate.setText("");
        txtStartTime.setText("");
        txtEndTime.setText("");
        chkPrinter.setSelected(false);
        rbYes.setSelected(false);
        rbNo.setSelected(false);
        txtareaMessage.setText("");
    }

    // Radio Buttons need to be set to group so only one can be selected at a time
    // If Radio Btn Yes is checked, enable txt area message, else disable
    // Set Toggle Buttons to toggle between AM & PM

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

When I select either of the radio buttons, it does not seem to be making the text area editable.

Comment: Please remove the unrelevant methods and fields to reduce the amount of useless code. Plus, precise which method has been assigned to which component, it is no possible to tell that just by looking (you can also show the relevant FXML code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of JavaFX controls is represented by [observable properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). So the `RadioButton` has a `selectedProperty` and the `TextArea` has a `editableProperty`. You can set and retrieve the values of these with the usual set/get (or set/is) methods: `txtareaMessage.setEditable(rbYes.isSelected())`, you can also observe them for changes:

```
rbYes.selectedProperty().addListener(...);
```

or you can bind the value of one property to the value of another. Binding essentially just registers a listener with one property and updates the other property when the observed property changes.

In your case the logic is very simple (the value of the text area's editable property should be the same as the value of the radio button's selected property), so all you need is to establish a simple binding in the `initialize()` method:

```
txtareaMessage.editableProperty().bind(rbYes.selectedProperty());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(rbYes.isSelected() && !rbNo.isSelected()) {
        txtareaMessage.setEditable(true);
        message = txtareaMessage.getText();
    }
    else {
        txtareaMessage.setEditable(false);
        message = "None";
    }
```

That segment of code is within an `ActionListener` for your button (`handleBtnSubmit`), therefore from what I understand, you need an `ActionListener` on your radio buttons to fire the code aforementioned.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an ToggleGroup like this.

   ```
   final ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
   ```
2. Add the Radiobuttons to the "group".

   ```
   RadioButton yes = new RadioButton("yes");   
   yes.setToggleGroup(group);

   RadioButton no= new RadioButton("no");    
   no.setToggleGroup(group);
   ```
3. Check if the "yes" RadioButton is selected.

   ```
    yes.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if(yes.isSelected()){
             textField.setEnabled(true);

        }else{
             textField.setEnabled(false);
        }
      }
   });
   ```